# Detect Amazon VM (Windows)

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, virtualization

Is there any way to programmatically detect that my C/C++ Windows application is running on an Amazon Cloud server? E.g., any APIs, WScripts, or environment variables? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make a HTTP GET against `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/` on the instance.
On EC2(windows or *nix), you will receive information about the instance

See:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

Comment: This is probably the easiest way and cross platform. There is a config service that is installed for windows instances only.